# How do I create a front-end JavaScript library from multiple TypeScript files?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I am trying to create a JavaScript library as a single file for use in a web client (the front end), using TypeScript sources that are broken into multiple files.

Since this is going to be used by a web browser, most of the module import syntaxes (`umd`, `es6`, `system`, etc.) will not work. And for that matter, since I want this to also be reasonably quick to load, using the new `<script type="module">` syntax is not going to suffice for what I want. (I already tried it, and I could not get it to work anyway.) I also do not want to have to import a third-party modules library like RequireJS or SystemJS.

I have also tried using WebPack to combine all of the modular files, but to my dismay, it appears to keep the modular syntax and just concatenates the files, sometimes even mangling class names in the process. For instance:

```
export
class BERElement extends ASN1Element {
```

became:

```
// CONCATENATED MODULE: ./built/modules/ber.js
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "BERElement", function() { return ber_BERElement; });

class ber_BERElement extends ASN1Element {
```

So, to reiterate: **how, given a TypeScript library that is broken up among several files, do I produce a JavaScript library that**:

- Is one single file
- Runs in a web browser
- Does not require third-party dependencies to load in a web browser

?

Comment: I would want to add two more requirement for the generated JS library:
1. Runs (could be imported and used) in node environment in a straightforward way
2. The library imports and uses other external libraries (TS and JS), and I need those to be built in the same file.
Can all that be achieved without Webpack or similar?